# Why is there difference between MTU size and packet size in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

My host machine is ubuntu and guest machine is windows 7.

I'm generating traffic on windows 7 and capturing its traffic in the middle on ubuntu with wireshark.

Both host and guest machines' MTU is 1500 bytes, but i see no packet with size more than 1430 bytes in wireshark.

1430 bytes is for (application data + tcp and ip headers) and the size on wire is 1444 bytes.

My question is that why the packets don't have the size of 1500 considering (application data + tcp and ip headers) ?

Comment: What is printed if you run `netsh interface ipv6 show subinterfaces` and `netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces` at the command line on the Windows 7 guest?

Comment: for ipv4: mtu is 1500 for "Local Area Connection" and mtu is 4294967295 for "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1"

Comment: for ipv6: mtu is 1500 for "Local Area Connection" and mtu is 1280 for both "Local Area Connection* 11" and "isatap.domain.name" and mtu is  4294967295 for "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1"